# Rename file name in F# and Visual Studio 2012 does not work

Tags: file, f#, project, rename

1. Create new F# Console project
2. Rename `Program.fs` to `program.fs`
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Reopen Visual Studio and the Console project
5. The file name is back to `Program.fs`

How can I rename that file? I have Windows 8 x64 and Visual Studio 2012 SP2 Ultimate.

Comment: This is probably related to the fact that in windows file names are case-insensitive but stored with case sensitivity.  The rename probably doesn't do anything

Comment: So is it a bug or "feature"? Then I probably have to change the name to something else like `rogram.fs` and then back to `program.fs`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename it to something else first, then to 'program.fs'.